# Finding the mistake in precalc equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{x-1} = -1;\tag{1}$$ $$ \mathbb{D}=[1,\infty)\tag{2}$$
$$x+3=(-1-\sqrt{x-1})^2\tag{3}$$
$$x+3=1+2\sqrt{x-1}+x-1\tag{4}$$
$$x_{1/2} = \pm\sqrt{\frac 3 2}+1\tag{5}$$
$$\mathbb{D} -> x=\sqrt{\frac 3 2}+1\tag{6} $$
According to the solution there shouldn't be any value for x.


Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look eqution (1), you see that left hand of equation is always positive, thus there isn't no solution for this equation.

Answer (score 0):

When you square both sides, going from (1) to (3), you bring in extra solutions that aren't right for equation (1).